# ReferenceError in filter date with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, time

```
$scope.dates = new Date();
var ed = new Date($filter('date')($scope.dates,'hh:mm:ss'));
```

in the second line I want to get time, but I get reference error.

What is my problem?

```
 (function(){

var app = angular.module('notesApp',['angular-markdown-editable']);

 app.controller('notesController', function($scope, $interval){

function updateTime() {
  $scope.dates = new Date();
  var ed = new Date($filter('date')($scope.dates,'hh:mm:ss'));
  alert(ed);
      }
...
```

Comment: can you show us the controller or directive  or service definition? I would need to see how you are injecting `$fitler`

Comment: @Dalorzo I do it in function

Comment: I need to see the angular component declaration

Comment: answer provided below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject `$filter` in your **controller** declaration like:

```
app.controller('notesController', function($scope, $interval, $filter){ // <-- filter was added at the end
```

I understand this issue is about angular but I would advise that you consider using javascript date functions like:

```
var date = new Date();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var hour = date.getHours();
```